# PHP Unix to Date

Tags: php, date, strtotime, epoch

When I `var_dump` a particular variable, I get:

`'date' => int 1410307200`

When I `var_dump` `date('F j Y', strtotime($start_date))`, I get:

`string 'January 1 1970' (length=14)`

I get the same output when I don't use `strtotime`.

Why does it keep returning the epoch time?

Comment: I'd check to make sure `$start_date` is what you think it is. Running `echo date('F j Y', 1410307200);` gives me an expected output of: "September 9 2014"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `strtotime()` on a Unix Timestamp. That's redundant and an error:

```
echo date('F j Y', $start_date)
```